# SP Online Library conditional data selection

Tags: sharepoint-online, document-library, modern-experience, managed-metadata, json-formatting

Is it possible to have two columns in a library that are related so that if column 'Department' is selected it allows column 'Parts' to list only parts of this department?

And if Department is not selected, no options are available in Parts.
Should Department be changed, Parts gets reset.

Ideally Department and Parts should get its data from a list so that it can be maintained.

I don't want to use a form as users will work directly in the library.

Any ideas appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to achieve this requirements in SharePoint online.

1. Using JSON formatting (as you tagged your question with [json-formatting](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/json-formatting) tag):

   You can build cascading drop down fields using `inlineEditField` in JSON and save values to list columns with the help of `setValue` action.

   Refer this link for example JSON: [Dependent-DropDown](https://github.com/Fedes365/Microsoft-Lists-Templates/tree/main/Dependent-DropDown)

   [image]

---

2. Using Power Apps (If you want to use file "Properties" form):

   You can use Power apps to customize the library file "Properties" form and develop cascading drop downs with the help of functions/formula.

   Check below links for detailed information and tutorial:

   1. [Create dependent drop-down lists in a canvas app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/dependent-drop-down-lists)
   2. [Working with Cascading Lists in SharePoint and Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/working-with-cascading-lists-in-sharepoint-and-powerapps)

   [image]