# Dependent drop-down in list

Tags: sharepoint-online, list, modern-experience, list-form, powerapp

How city can be dependent on the province?

What will be the method to do this in the SharePoint list?

Answer (score 0):

You can use Power apps to customize the SharePoint list form and develop cascading (dependent) drop downs with the help of Power Apps functions/formulas.

Check below links for detailed information and tutorial:

1. [Create dependent drop-down lists in a canvas app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/power-apps/maker/canvas-apps/dependent-drop-down-lists)
2. [Working with Cascading Lists in SharePoint and Power Apps](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoft-365/community/working-with-cascading-lists-in-sharepoint-and-powerapps)

[image]

**Similar thread**: [SP Online Library conditional data selection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305322/sp-online-library-conditional-data-selection/305324#305324)

---

**Update from comments**:

1. For dependent drop downs on "list forms", you can either use Power Apps (easy option) or [SPFx Form Customizer extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-form-customizer) - coding experience required.
2. If you are looking for dependent drop down in "list view" - you can use JSON formatting check my answer at: [SP Online Library conditional data selection](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305322/sp-online-library-conditional-data-selection/305324#305324)

Comment: Any alternatives without powerapps?

Comment: For "list forms", you can either use Power Apps (easy option) or [SPFx Form Customizer extension](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/extensions/get-started/building-form-customizer) - coding experience required.

Comment: If you are looking for dependent drop down in "list view" - you can use JSON formatting check my answer at: https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/305322/sp-online-library-conditional-data-selection/305324#305324